# Dojo 1.7.2 not working with local file

Tags: dojo

I'm new to dojo, so I followed an example:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/layout

This works fine ...

Now if I use the src 1.7.2 that I've downloaded on my domino server, I get an error:
Could not load class 'dijit/layout/BorderContainer

If I look with firebug, the dojo.js loads along with others .js ans .css files.

I cannot understand why it does not work ...

The HTML file is at the root of the server and contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dojo-release-1.7.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script src='./dojo-release-1.7.2-src/dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config='parseOnLoad: true'></script>
<script>require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/AccordionPane"]);</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Top pane</div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #1">accordion pane #1</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #2">accordion pane #2</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #3">accordion pane #3</div>
 </div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="tab #1">tab pane #1</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="tab #2">tab pane #2</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="tab #3">tab pane #3</div>
 </div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'trailing'">Trailing pane</div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">Bottom pane</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's pretty sure I've missed somenting...
all help welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

The require statement uses slashes, but the markup should use periods.

Change throughout your example.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
```

should be

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
```

Comment: ok I've tried and still not working BUT now I do not get the error but a blank page, nothing shows up :( in addition i'm wondering why the markup "/" works with online dojo.js??? ps: thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: in fact I need to remove the <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" > in order to see something... any ideas why?

Comment: The border container needs an explicit height and width.  With height 100%, you also need to give the html and body nodes a height of 100%

Comment: thanks , at least but not last , it's working :) still don't understand why with online files it was working without these changes but i giveup.

Comment: The link you posted is using an unreleased version of Dojo.  So maybe there is a change coming in a future release that supports the slashes.  That being said, I spent some time yesterday looking through the source control for the change and couldn't find it.  Also, the width and height css is specified, just in a different snippet of code.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. now i've to manage to have my old (1.6.1) custom build to work in 1.7.2.

Comment: If you get stuck, post it as a question.  I'll answer with the changes I made to my Ant script to build Dojo.